How to apply conditional formatting on Calculation Group Item?
I need to apply conditional formattingon newly created Calculation Item within my Calculation Group. Basically, I have there 4 Items:
enter image description here
I created matrix, [Total Invoiced Amount] is my measure put in Value Area:
enter image description here
Now, I need to format background color of YoYPerc column, based on simple condition: if YoYPerc > 5% then green, if > 0 and < 5 then yellow, else red.
I'm struggling doing it, here are my efforts:
#1 - here I return numbers, not HEX
YoYFormatting =
VAR vYoYValue = CALCULATE(SELECTEDMEASURE(), 'Time Intelligence Yrs'[Measure Years] = "YoYPerc")
RETURN
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    vYoYValue >=0, 0,
    vYoYValue >0.05, 1,
    2
    )

#2 - here I return HEX
YoYFormatting =
VAR vYoYValue = CALCULATE(SELECTEDMEASURE(), 'Time Intelligence Yrs'[Measure Years] = "YoYPerc")
RETURN
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    vYoYValue >=0, "#ffd966",
    vYoYValue >0.05, "#6aa84f",
    "#FF0000"
    )

For #1 I used 'Conditional Formatting' on [Total Invoiced Amount], tried to choose YoYFormatting as Field Value but it can't be chosen, don't know why.
For #2 I used 'Conditional Formatting' on [Total Invoiced Amount] and set appropiate rules as shown below:
enter image description here
but table is formatted totally not properly, moreover column YoYPerc is not formatted at all:
enter image description here
How can I properly format Calculated Group Item? Is it possible at all?
I use the latest version of Power BI.

The first thing i noticed was the condition vYoYValue >= 0 will always be TRUE if the value is positive, so it would never reach the vYoYValue > 0.05 condition.  If you switch them round it should work. This works on my Power BI to create conditional formatting.
YoYFormatting = 
    VAR vYoYValue = CALCULATE(SELECTEDMEASURE(), 'Time Intelligence Yrs'[Measure Years] = "YoYPerc")
    RETURN
    SWITCH(
        TRUE(),
        vYoYValue > 0.05, "#6aa84f",   // Green color for YoY greater than 5%
        vYoYValue >= 0, "#ffd966",     // Yellow for YoY between 0% and 5%
        "#FF0000"                      // Red for negative YoY
    )

The other way to do it is to right click on the [Total Invoiced Amount] column in the visualizations, select conditional formatting, change format type to Rules and enter the formula that you want.

Thanks, I'll check it out and let you know soon!

Ok, so it doesn't work. I think it could work for seperate measures (added to Value Area), like YTD, YoY% etc. However, I need to format Calculation Item from Calculation Group. IF I add above measure to formatting in  [Total Invoiced Amount] as 'Field Value' then I get error: cannot convert value "#ffd966" of type Text to Numeric/Date. As for formatting 'Rules' I tried it before, it doesn't work properly on Calculation Group (you can't choose single column like YoY%, it's applied to the whole Calculated Group)
